An example of a matrix whose eigenvalues fullfill 'No-resonance' condition
No-resonance for a matrix is defined in terms of its eigenvalue as (last para page-3 in ref.):
$$\lambda_i \neq \sum_{j=1}^N m_j\lambda_j;\ \forall m_j\in \mathbb{Z}\ \ and\ m_j\geq 0$$
$$such\ that\ \sum_{j=1}^{n}m_j\geq 2$$
Or, No-resonance condition occurs if any eigenvalues can't be expressed as (positive) integer linear combination of the other eigenvalues. Where, the trivial case of $\lambda_j = \lambda_j +0 + 0+...$ is excluded.
Such conditions are crucial in studying nonlinear dynamical systems from where they are initially motivated.

My query:

Most of the matrices I have encountered don't satisfy 'No-resonance'. I want an example of a matrix whose eigenvalues have this exceptional property.


My approach:
I looked at this post on math.SE, here. A matrix is more likely to fulfil the 'No-resonance' condition if its eigenvalues are non-integral because $m_j$ are integers. Even in this case, some constraints on parameters $N$ and $m_j$ are required.
I am still searching for such matrices. I would highly appreciate it if I could get some hints/pointers for tackling the problem.

There has been a suggestion to look for a random matrix. They are more likely to fulfil this criterion. But, I don't find it helpful to develop a concrete example of the particular matrix I am looking for.

If you don't have a lot of dimensions, even integral eigenvalues give examples.  For example, if your eigenvalues are 2, and 3, you satisfy the no-resonance condition.

The matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&2\cr1&1\cr}
$$
has eigenvalues $1+\sqrt2$ and $1-\sqrt2$, neither of which is an integer multiple of the other.
